# Specify namespace in function argument c++

Tags: c++, arduino, namespaces, esp8266

How to specify which namespace used by passing in function argument in C++ (arduino)

The objective is to select a namespace depending on the mode the program is running. Of course, the mode may change at runtime.

```cpp
namespace A{
 void init(){}
 void run(){}
}

namespace B{
 void init(){}
 void run(){}
}

void function2(namespace X) { // this does not work.
 X::init();
 X::run();
}

void loop(){
 // mode is defined elsewhere (actually a switch function is used)
 if (mode == "A") {
  function2(A);
 } else if (mode == "B") {
  function2(B);
 }
}
```

Comment: Just removed `C` tag.

Comment: You cannot, you can still turn `namespace` into "`static` `class`" to be able to do it via template.

Comment: You don't. This has the distinct aroma of an XY problem. What is the actual problem X you're attempting to solve by doing this Y? You *could* do this with class types and a template `function2` pretty easily. But I'll save that gem for when you explain further.

Comment: `void main()` is not standard C++. Use `int main()` instead.

Comment: The idea is to use the main loop function (arduino) to determine in which mode the program is running. Modes A and B would have the same functions (init, start, stop, run, etc...) and depending on if the program is in mode A or B, these function would do something different. I thought namespaces would be a good idea for that.

Comment: No, namespaces would not be a good idea for that at all. You need a *base class* with *virtual member functions* `init` and `run`, and *derived classes* `A` and `B` that implement these functions, each in its own way. Then at run time you will select an *object* of class `A` or `B`, and run its member functions via a *pointer* or *reference* to the base class.

Comment: I don't see a relation to "arduino" nor "esp8266"

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass a namespace to a function (or method).

But you can pass a pointer to a function or method, like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

namespace A {
    void print() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
}

namespace B {
    void print() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
}

void function(void (*print)()) {
    print();
}

int main() {
    function(A::print);
    function(B::print);
}
```

*Note: `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is a GCC extension that expands to the pretty string name of the current function or method.*

Comment: This looks promising, but the namespaces can have multiple methods, so this won't work for me. I've edited the question to reflect that

Comment: Well, so WhozCraig was right, you described an XY problem. Until you enhance your question to reflect the _real_ issue correctly, I'll keep my answer. It might help others that look especially for namespace issues. -- Anyway, using namespace is the wrong solution for your problem. Use classes and a common base class.

Answer (score 1):

you can use macro in C like this

```
#define function2(x)  { using namespace x ; print();}
```

full source:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace A{
 void print(){
     cout << "namespace A\n";
 }
}

namespace B{
 void print(){
    cout << "namespace B\n";
 }
}
#define function2(x)  { using namespace x ; print();}

int main(){

    function2(A);
    function2(B);
}
```

tested at : https://godbolt.org/z/raq8Ks9cM

Comment: does this work if the namespaces have multiple methods (with the same name)? i edited the question to relect that

Comment: @will.mendil . yes it still works, you can test it with my code easily. lets try to replace  `print` with `init();`  and  ` run();`

Answer (score 0):

It is not valid to have a function parameter specifying a namespace as you have in your example. From [Storage class specifiers 7.1.1.2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf):

> a variable declared as a function parameter has automatic storage duration by default.

But the concept of storage duration is applicable only to **objects**. And since namespaces are not objects(and neither are they types), they don't have storage duration and thus the syntax that you've in your program is incorrect. That is, we cannot pass a namespace as a function argument.

You can instead have a parameter as a pointer to a function as shown below.

Additionally, note that `void main()` is not standard C++. You should instead use `int main()` as shown below.

```
#include <iostream>
namespace A{
 void print(){
     std::cout<<"A::print() called"<<std::endl;
 }
 void run(){
    std::cout<<"A::run() called"<<std::endl;
 }
}

namespace B{
 void print(){
     std::cout<<"B::print() called"<<std::endl;
 }
 void run(){
    std::cout<<"B::run() called"<<std::endl;
 }
}
//-------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv-------->function2 has a parameter named print that is a pointer to a function taking no parameters and with return type of void
void function2(void (*print)()) { 
 print();
}

int main(){//void main() changed to int main()
 function2(A::print);
 function2(A::run);
 
 function2(B::print);
 function2(B::run);
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/3ymkytUXUE)

Comment: I've edited the question as the namespaces would have multiple methods associated, so this won't work.

Comment: @will.mendil This will work with multiple functions as well. See [demo](https://onlinegdb.com/3ymkytUXUE). I have also shown this in my modified answer. Check out my edited answer.